# No color with Samsung C48x on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

In the past I was using Ubuntu 20.04 and my printer C48x was working well (grey, color, scanning, etc)
While on a long stay elsewhere I updated my PC to Ubuntu 22.04. with no printer available.
Comming back home, my printer now does only grey printings

I assigned to the printer
the driver "Samsung C48x Series PS" Version 1.8 from the database
and the "Samsung-C48x-Postscript-Samsung.ppd" downloaded from somewhere in the Internet

I tried the printer under windows and it worked well without any problem.

I have only little knowledge about ubuntu and no good picture, what the benefit of the CUPS is, therefore I have really no idea what I could do to solve my problem?!?

Comment: Possibly https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1971242.

Comment: I tried a hint from    Bernard Stafford proposed the following answer:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-c480-color-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462546/model/16462552
Samsung Linux Print and Scan Driver V1.00.39_01.1
and it works :-)